# Golang RESTAPI returns wrong data

Tags: sql, rest, go, mariadb, go-gin

When i use the debugger the `metricId` returns the Metric Object with all `0 or null` values (same as the output).

*what am i doing wrong here?*

`The Database connection works.`

```
func GetMetricById(c *gin.Context) {
    metricId := c.Param("id")

    conn := config.DatabaseConnect()

    var obj models.Metric

    rows := conn.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM Metric WHERE id = ?", metricId)

    err := rows.Scan(&obj.Id, &obj.Sms, &obj.Absence, &obj.Pregnant, &obj.Uwv_notifications, &obj.Wia_dossiers_started, &obj.Employees, &obj.Data_id, &obj.Date, &obj.Type)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(obj, "Metric Object that is called.")

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, obj)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Sms": 0,
    "Absence": 0,
    "Pregnant": 0,
    "Uwv_notifications": 0,
    "Wia_dossiers_started": 0,
    "Employees": 0,
    "Data_id": 0,
    "Date": "",
    "Type": 0
}
```

Comment: How the `models.Metric` looks like ? Does the table `Metric` has a right name ?

Comment: Yes it does Philidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANSWER]

```
func GetMetricsByDataId(c *gin.Context) {
    queryParams := c.Request.URL.Query()
    
    conn := config.DatabaseConnect()
    var metrObject []models.Metric

    rows, _ := conn.Query("SELECT * FROM Metric WHERE data_id = ?", queryParams.Get("data_id"))

    defer rows.Next()

    for rows.Next() {
        var obj models.Metric
        if err := rows.Scan(&obj.Id, &obj.Sms, &obj.Absence, &obj.Pregnant, &obj.Uwv_notifications, &obj.Wia_dossiers_started, &obj.Employees, &obj.Data_id, &obj.Date, &obj.Type); err != nil {
            _ = fmt.Errorf(err.Error())
        }
        metrObject = append(metrObject, obj)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        _ = fmt.Errorf(err.Error())
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, metrObject)
}
```

Like this it works

`localhost:8082/billing/getmetricbydataid?data_id=150295`

With this API call

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution may be to use `metricId := c.Params.ByName("id")` instead of `metricId := c.Param("id")`

Comment: i tried it but it is still the same.

Comment: How are you doing the request? like "url/:id"?

Comment: ``localhost:8082/billing/getmetricbyid?data_id=150295``

Comment: you should use `localhost:8082/billing/getmetricbyid?id=150295` if you are using path parameters, if not use `localhost:8082/billing/getmetricbyid/150295`